Producer-consumer problem with queue and semaphore
In Stroustrup's book The C++ Programming Language, there is a code example that demonstrates the use of condition variables:
class Message {    // object to be communicated
      //...
};

queue<Message> mqueue;           // the queue of messages
condition_variable mcond;        // the variable communicating events
mutex mmutex;                    // the locking mechanism

A producer writes to the queue, and a consumer reads it from the queue.
void producer()
{
     while(true) {
          Message m;
           //... fill the message ...
          unique_lock<mutex> lck {mmutex};   // protect operations
          mqueue.push(m);
          mcond.notify_one();                // notify
     }                                       // release lock (at end of scope)
}

The code for consumer:
void consumer()
{
     while(true) {
          unique_lock<mutex> lck{mmutex};              // acquire mmutex
          mcond.wait(lck,[this]{ return !mqueue.empty(); });          // release lck and wait until not empty;
                                                       // re-acquire lck upon wakeup
          auto m = mqueue.front();                     // get the message
          mqueue.pop();
          lck.unlock();                                // release lck
           //... process m ...
     }
}

I understand how this works. Could you explain the difference between this approach and an implementation using a semaphore? I reviewed this and this, but I’m still unclear on the distinctions in this specific case.
Is there anything wrong with an implementation with semaphore instead of condition variable?
Initialize counting semaphore as
std::counting_semaphore filled(0);

Producer code and consumer code :
void producer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Message m;
        //... fill the message ...  
        {
            std::scoped_lock lck(mmutex);
            mqueue.push(m);
        }
        filled.release();
    }
}

void consumer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        filled.acquire();
        {
            std::scoped_lock lck(mmutex);
            auto m = mqueue.front();
            mQueue.pop();
            // ... process m ....
        }
    }
}

I understand filled.release() call in producer will keep incrementing the counter, if consumer code doesn't run. Other than that is there a problem with this code?
Does filled.acquire() have a busy-wait loop wasting CPU cycles? Even if it has, won't it break out of the loop as soon as the first Message is pushed by the producer?

For one thing, std::counting_semaphore is a relatively recent invention (new in C++20) whereas std::condition_variable existed since C++11.

@IgorTandetnik Yes I understand that. But in the general sense (not necessarity in c++), is there an issue with the semaphore solution?

In this particular example, both approaches work. The condition you are protecting is "the queue is empty" which can be represented as "semaphore counter is zero". But try this: "wait until the message is available and process it, but unblock and exit the loop when a bool stop variable becomes true". I mean, in a real program your producer and consumer probably won't run forever. std::condition_variable can handle an arbitarily complex condition, one that may not be easily reduced to simple counting.

@IgorTandetnik yes makes sense. Thanks!

Counted semaphores work fine for queues (in fact, the first thread-safe queue I ever wrote used a counted semaphore, and I've used it repeatedly for decades now). For a queue, I think it leads to code that's cleaner and easier to understand than a CV.
